# The user denied permission to access the database. What the Firebase Remote Config error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I installed Firebase Remote Config, but for some users, it is absolutely not clear why an error occurs when receiving data.
I tried to find something similar, but unfortunately there is nothing
Help)
Error code: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Remote Config: Error thrown when opening storage. Original error: The user denied permission to access the database.. (remoteconfig/storage-open). [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7F4S.png)

Here is how it is implemented in my code now

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import bridge from "@vkontakte/vk-bridge";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/remote-config";

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "loans-vk-app.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "loans-vk-app",
  storageBucket: "loans-vk-app.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "***",
});

export const Context = createContext(null);

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const remoteConfig = firebase.remoteConfig();
remoteConfig.settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis = 7200000;

// Init VK  Mini App
bridge.send("VKWebAppInit");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Context.Provider
    value={{
      firebase,
      firestore,
      remoteConfig,
    }}
  >
    <App />
  </Context.Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  import("./eruda").then(({ default: eruda }) => {}); //runtime download
}
```

[next code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46uL.png)

tried to update to web version 9, but the error does not go away